# Does allowing extra parameters break type safety in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion, type-safety

Consider this example: ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgDFAvFAFADwPwC4oGdgBOAlgHYDmAlEgHxQBuA9kQCYBQoksAjEqlYrUYt24aDABMvdDhIBXALYAjCAX6CmbVgGMGJfFABmcHPClo1UHXoYAbCADobDMugA0UDhAYH0FCtt19Ay4THmQjAL1gQ3ETSXCuVlYjFAByXFT-A3EULioAenzDBAZZYDAy3Cgud1S5JRV3RTKoeuUCKCIqkgZolHxicigAHyhZEmYIA1IIZn8gA))

```
type F0 = (x?: string) => void
type F1 = () => void
type F2 = (x: number) => void

const f0: F0 = (x) => console.log(x, typeof(x))
const f1: F1 = f0
const f2: F2 = f1

f0('s')
f2(1) // f0 outputs 1, 'number', but number is not (string | undefined)
```

Here, type `F0` expects the first parameter `x` to be `string | undefined`, so it is assignable to type `F1`, which takes no parameters. This is acceptable, since calling a function of type `F0` would pass an implicit `undefined` as the first parameter.

In TypeScript, type `F1` is assignable to type `F2` because extra parameters are allowed. The idea is that a function of type `F1` would simply ignore the extra parameters.

However, the problem is that `F1` is assignable to `F2`, and a call to a function of type `F2` is incompatible with the expected type in a call to a function of type `F0`, which is assignable to `F1` but not `F2`. Assigning `F0` to `F1` seems safe, but assigning `F1` to `F2` does not seem safe. The code compiles even with `strict` (and thus `strictFunctionTypes`) enabled.

---

## Real-world example

This is a real-world example of how it can be a problem:

```
function processData (optionalData?: DataType) {
  // implementation expects optionalData to be DataType | undefined
}

// somewhere, processData is converted into () => void
const handler: () => void = processData

// somewhere, handler is used on a DOM event handler, which passes an Event object as the first argument, which is not what processData expects
element.addEventListener('click', handler) // bad, but allowed
element.addEventListener('click', () => handler()) // OK
```

Comment: F0 => F1 => F2 is valid, but F0 => F2 is not. All assignments in F0 => F1 => F2 are valid, but assigning F2 to F0 is not. You are "working around" the assignment with this setup, essentially.

Comment: @caTS My question is about whether making `F1` assignable to `F2` is unsound because it can lead to the type violation described.

Comment: But it should be sound! It's a function that doesn't care what it's given and always returns `void`. Also, I think it's very hard to make the compiler "smart enough" to see these kinds of unsound assignments.

Comment: @caTS Then isn't making `F0` assignable to `F1` unsound because a function of type `F0` cares about the first parameter (must be `string | undefined`)? If `() => void` is "a function that doesn't care what it's given", then `f2 = f1` is sound, but `f1 = f0` is not. Alternatively, if `() => void` is "a function that takes an infinite series of `undefined`", then `f1 = f0` is sound, but `f2 = f1` is not.

Comment: `F1 extends F2` is sound.  It's `F0 extends F1` that's technically unsound, but it's so useful that it's allowed.  See [this comment on ms/TS#42479](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42479#issuecomment-767226743) which talks about properties instead of function parameters, but it's essentially the same argument.  ^Victor, yes, exactly.

Comment: So then the answer to this question is "no, allowing extra parameters does not break type safety; your example breaks type safety elsewhere", along with information explaining how TS intentionally allows some unsound actions for various reasons.  Does that make sense?  Should someone write that up as an answer? (me?)  Let me know (and mention @jcalz in your reply to ping me).

Comment: @jcalz The call `f1(1)` would result in `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.`, which is why I originally thought `() => void` expects all arguments to be `undefined` and thought `F0 extends F1` should be sound while `F1 extends F2` is unsound. Is there anything that clarifies whether `() => void` means "a function that takes an infinite series of `undefined`" or "a function that takes anything"? Your linked example suggests it should be the latter, but is there another source confirming it?

Comment: It’s a function that takes anything, but when compared to optional parameters it is unsoundly treated like a function that might assume that a defined argument is a particular type. The compiler complains about passing extra arguments in a roughly analogous way to how it complains about excess properties; it is not *unsound* to allow it, but there’s an error because it’s probably a developer mistake. If I write up an answer I will provide sources, but is there anything else that needs to be covered by it or have we addressed everything? (Ping me via @jcalz)

Comment: @jcalz I think that's all. The answer should include these points: `() => void` means a function that takes anything, `F1 extends F2` is sound, `F0 extends F1` is unsound, `f1(1)` is sound but disallowed for other reasons, and `F0 extends F1` is allowed for convenience even though it's unsound, as a consequence of TypeScript design decisions.

Comment: I will also add a real-world example that led to this question.

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance; it probably won't be for a number of hours.

Comment:  I can't finish my answer tonight, it's bedtime in my time zone. I'll do it tomorrow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical answer to this question is that you've found a type safety hole (although it's due to optional parameters, not extra parameters), and that this is a design limitation of TypeScript.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#13043](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13043).

---

At the outset it's probably best to consider [*soundness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) and [*completeness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)) of a [static type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Static_type_checking). A type system is sound if it never allows unsafe operations. A type system is complete if it never prohibits safe operations.  It is impossible to have a [decidable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)) type system for JavaScript that is both sound and complete, but surely TypeScript is at least *sound*, right? And while it can't also be complete, surely TypeScript only prohibits operations if it can't be sure that they are safe, right?  Right?

Well, as it turns out, *TypeScript intentionally allows certain operations that are not
[type safe](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness).* There are holes in the type system, and it's possible to write code that falls through these holes, leading to runtime errors with no compiler warning to protect you.  TypeScript's type system is *intentionally unsound*. The holes are allowed to remain because the TypeScript team thinks that patching them would end up generating a lot of errors on perfectly good real-world code, and the added safety is not considered worth the inconvenience. It is one of the [official TypeScript Design *Non*-Goals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) to:

> Apply a sound or "provably correct" type system. Instead, strike a balance between correctness and productivity.

On the other hand, sometimes *TypeScript intentionally prohibits certain type safe operations*.  There are technically unnecessary obstacles, and it's possible to write code that runs into these obstacles, leading to compiler errors where no runtime problem would occur.  TypeScript's type system is *intentionally incomplete*.  There are essentially linter-like rules that warn the developer that they are probably making a mistake, even if they are not writing code that violates any fundamental type constraints.

So the type system is unsound and incomplete, on purpose.

---

TypeScript considers functions of fewer parameters to be assignable to functions of more parameters (see [relevant handbook doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#comparing-two-functions) and [FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-with-fewer-parameters-assignable-to-functions-that-take-more-parameters)) since it is almost always harmless for a function to receive more arguments than it expects.  Any arguments that don't have a corresponding parameter are just ignored at runtime.

So it is considered *sound* to allow this assignment:

```
type F1 = () => void
const f1: F1 = () => console.log("");

type F2 = (x: number) => void
const f2: F2 = f1
```

After all, `f1` ignores any argument it receives, so calling `f2` with an argument doesn't hurt anything:

```
f1(); // ""
f2(1); // ""
```

But then why does the compiler prohibit this?

```
f1(1); // compiler error, Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
```

This is one of those intentional incompletnesses.  The function `f1()` is *known* to ignore any inputs it receives, so it's probably a developer mistake to pass in an argument.  I scoured the docs and GitHub issues for some official source for this, but it seems to be so obvious that it doesn't have to be mentioned: probably nobody wants to *intentionally* call a function *directly* with too many arguments.  (If someone knows a good source for this, let me know.)

But wait, if nobody wants to do this, why is the assignment above considered sound?  Because people *do* want to do *this*:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr.forEach(x => console.log(x.toFixed(1))); //  "1.0" "2.0" "3.0"    
arr.forEach(() => console.log("")); // "" "" ""

arr.forEach(f2); // "" "" ""
arr.forEach(f1); // "" "" ""
```

You're not *directly* calling the callback with more arguments than it needs, but the implementation of `forEach()` is doing that, and it's not a problem.

The alternative would be requiring you to do this:

```
arr.forEach((val, ind, arr) => f2(val)) // "" "" ""
arr.forEach((val, ind, arr) => f1()) // "" "" ""
```

which is obnoxious (and the stated reason for this rule in the documentation).

So the assignment is allowed because it's useful and sound, but the direct call is prohibited because it's useless, although still sound.

---

When TypeScript compares functions for compatibility, optional and required parameters are interchangeable. Extra optional parameters of the source type are not an error ([relevant handbook doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#optional-parameters-and-rest-parameters)).  This is very useful, because it allows people to treat optional parameters the same as missing parameters, and as long as you're only every directly calling the functions, it's fine:

```
type F0 = (x?: string) => void
const f0: F0 = (x) => console.log(x?.toUpperCase())
f0('abc') // "ABC"

type F1 = () => void
const f1: F1 = f0
f1(); // undefined
```

But this is unsound, since the following should be type safe:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(f1) //  RUNTIME ERROR! 
// x.toUpperCase is not a function
```

Oops!  That's a hole in the type system.  The compiler prevents you from making this mistake if you do it *directly*:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(f0) // compiler error
//                ~~ <-- number not assignable to string
```

---

So, as you've discovered, assignability in TypeScript is *not transitive* (see [microsoft/TypeScript#47499](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47499) and the tree of issues it links to), and therefore the type system is not sound.

The problem comes up in several places where "optional" and "missing" are conflated.  [Optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) have the same hole, as shown [in this comment on microsoft/TypeScript#47331](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47331#issuecomment-1011306664), since it is `{x: number} extends {}` is correctly allowed, and `{x: number} extends {x?: string}` is correctly rejected, but `{} extends {x?: string}` is incorrectly (but oh so usefully) allowed.

---

In summary, given:

```
type F0 = (x?: string) => void
declare let f0: F0;
type F1 = () => void
declare let f1: F1;
type F2 = (x: number) => void
declare let f2: F2;
```

This assignment is sound and allowed:

```
f2 = f1; // sound, true negative
```

while this assignment is unsound but allowed

```
f1 = f0; // unsound, false negative
```

And when combined, the unsoundness bites us with a runtime error.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4CgkikAXATxmQDEAGJAXiQAoAPAfgC4koTNgsAlAwB8SAG4B7DABNCxeBOA8kAMxpdaDZiyH1RCpRIA2EAHRGJWVm1MkJAVRiU0AYRBQITAQLlE1TAHIQACN4AKEAegikACIAQQAhFxj8X1IKagBGLS8RcSlZYiQDZRVMjWzGNTSyrwBuJCikAFdgaQgVDGAIWTTySiQqACYcli5gZrBgiDRdUUkZNJKSVSGNEarMvrQyPDSilSGmTIEGpoAlewA5ABUASQBZAFEkJ-PzlHOAQiRAXg3AUp2kCxbA4nDM3B4kBgoEhgBIViBVK14CQMIo0gBfYogEjwAAWzAgQlwxUUUGMZgsViJSAx+Dp+FAkFgCGQAGUJK1pHEoFBsMBIMAVgQ+hlBpVmHN8osistVOVxTkpSUKeZLEwYr9ALI7MVOqSK-WoG2040m01meQWhXkZJWh3WWjK+uItVOjWimp1NSOJzOHu1KRqmWObqaCjAMAwJjQSBmaAkaAANK8WJQUT0kHQQGgsJMIEKoMngs0Vlh4UhMqZnUQ5dmY4wANqZZNDZMAZgAunU0nXTCoE08EHjWHkVSY1VZgXYqBgWD0Q94-UQYpWaDFYkNTGvYm2t+viD20Gg+wOh0xcnpSYZx1SNb9AJI7utD-sfsQf681j+rSF7-bQg-xJhDmfN8dVAj8A0PY8-wA4cyhAz0ILAxCkG-X9T0ApgxBAIxky6aRkzrKVDiwnDvHdcDKMQqCT3-M9SNwqE2kIo9iODcimhQrjINSBkmWgOBECQexDC5Hk+SwAV82Fb9DUGOhGGsLgeD4QRLQKJZbVUdR5NGZUyVVW92BBRxnAhTxvBqGhAhCMJIg9RJklksUqAlC95g02UtLKCpHRoIN6gorkOi6Hptl2AgiiKJsW3bDtaNgoCTgogEkEuW5HheN4Pm+IETLBVx3GQaFYXLREVGRVF0SKLF4BxfFCWJK9yRvdUaQZA0dj2KLiBipBWyQTsErPNR7NJCMoxmWMjwTZMJimKa4QRXl+RCExSAkbheC6LBMWxXECSYGkSTHSk2qEBk+PAATWSQFxFHgIxmj5RRuuIOTNEU9hlO2-gpStNJ2ke7NkBMO0dNobsDRctz-s84ggaMEGkDB+UKih96XONVhTQWi1LwBopEeR1H7UGIZu29R1MiXckuWTXhmmQbosBxDAxAgIM-KXVo6eY1QcMhFm2Y5ooqaqGgl3DGAwYgBm0CZpAYAkPlUQ5tJ6VSIA)